# Execute multiple SQL commands at once on R

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rmysql, r-dbi

I am using RMySQL and DBI for the connection between R and MySQL

```
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI, quietly = TRUE)
```

Everything is working fine for one command, such as

```
sql = "select * from clients"
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user=user, password=password, dbname=dbname, host=host)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
data <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
huh <- dbHasCompleted(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
```

However, when I want to execute multiple commands with ";" between them (such as to set a parameter), it returns error. For example

```
sql = "SET @LAST_TEN_DAY = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 DAY); select * from clients where date > @LAST_TEN_DAY"
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user=user, password=password, dbname=dbname, host=host)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
data <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
huh <- dbHasCompleted(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
```

Many thanks,

Comment: You cant SQL and R like that. You have to create a variable that will hold the value of `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL, -10 DAY)` and then use the SQL query `SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE DATE> your variable value`

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for answering. May I know how to do so in R? Because if you execute an SQL command for creating a variable, I am not sure if that variable will be kept for the next SQL command execution.

Comment: The variable will be global and can be used for any sql statement within your R code.

Comment: Give me a reproducible example of your dataset by copying the output of  `dput(clients)`

Comment: Sure, please find a sampled data as follows structure `(list(name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Anna", 
"Ciaran", "Hannah", "Roisin"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2015-12-12 00:00:00", "2016-01-22 00:00:00", 
"2016-02-12 00:00:00", "2016-03-08 00:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(27, 28, 22, 19), job = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("data analyst", "operator"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", 
"date", "age", "job"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: found one extra closing bracket, correct code is... list(name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Anna", "Ciaran", "Hannah", "Roisin"), class = "factor"),  date = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2015-12-12 00:00:00", "2016-01-22 00:00:00", "2016-02-12 00:00:00", "2016-03-08 00:00:00"), class = "factor"), age = c(27, 28, 22, 19), job = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L ),  .Label = c("data analyst", "operator"), class = "factor"), .Names = c("name", "date", "age", "job"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For multiple commands we need to work as follows. The dbSendQuery will save the parameter

```
sql = "select * from clients where date > @LAST_TEN_DAY"
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user=user, password=password, dbname=dbname, host=host)
dbSendQuery(con, 'SET @LAST_TEN_DAY = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 DAY)')
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
data <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
huh <- dbHasCompleted(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
```